# how do you build one of those tab style buttons in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[I mean this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpUJK.jpg) which only allows one option to be selected

Comment: you can create your own widget to do that, that's one of the advantages of Flutter

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CupertinoSegmentedControl` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoSegmentedControl-class.html

Comment: is there anything that looks material design?